# How to add value for a key for which pattern is matched in perl

Tags: perl

I am learning perl hash and I am stuck at a point. Could you please help me to resolve the situation.

I am reading a file and storing the line number and data in hash and printing in Excel. Currently i am implementing hash variable. My requirement is to match a pattern in the line and store a string if the match found.

```
cat file1
line1 abc line1a .
line2 ddf line2a
line3 dde line3a
....
....
%value={ 1:
        line1 abc line1a => "somestring"
      2: 
        line2 ddf line2a => ""
      ...}
```

I am using following code for now

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature "say";
use Data Dumper;

my $No=1;
my %value;

open(INPUT,"file1");

while (<INPUT>) {
    $value{$No}{$_}="";
    $No=$No+1;
}
close <INPUT>
```

Could you please suggest something here. Also i have more than 150 lines in my file.

Excepted

```
         ------------------------------------- -----------------------
         |         Question                   |         Answer       |
         ------------------------------------- -----------------------
         | How many Teams are present         |    10                |
         ------------------------------------- ----------------------
         | Total no of participate joined     |     234              |
         ------------------------------------- -----------------------
         | No of player`s name Start with L   |                      |
         ------------------------------------- -----------------------
         | Total No of MoM won by Team        |     Team F           |
         ------------------------------------- -----------------------
```

And i am creating XLS format using EXCEL::Writer::XLSX module. Still not yet implemented as i am stuck in collecting the data

Comment: `close INPUT;`, btw. And use [lexical file handles and 3-argument `open`](https://perlmaven.com/open-files-in-the-old-way) for good measure.

Comment: A top level array makes more sense than a hash if you're using line numbers as keys, too.

Comment: You already have `$.` built in as the line number.

Comment: @Shawn, If i use top level array then can it be assign values for only matched element and for other it could be empty.

Comment: You don't show which elements you want to match and which you don't. Where does 'somestring' come from in your example?

Comment: Actually i need to show. Its just one part which i implemented. Actually program is there a file and content of that file needs to fill in EXCEL i.e. in 'A' column and the values will be filled in B column. somestring will be filled in B column. somestring again will come from another file after doing post processing. My doubt is will clubbing in the values

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and include an example of what you want to appear in your Excel file? Also tell us if you are going to create CSV file, or if you want to produce an actual XLS or XLSX file in Perl.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to understand the question better.

You want to create a hash where

- key is the line number and data
- value is "somestring" if pattern matches and "" if not.

I will try to answer based on this understanding.
Let me know if it helped.

Assumptions - The input is a regular file.

A hash contains a key and  a value associated with it.
Eg: %value = ('A' => abc, 'B' => def, 'C' => ghi);

To get the following:

*%value={ 1:
line1 abc line1a => "somestring"
2:
line2 ddf line2a => ""
...}*

You can try something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data:Dumper;

my $pattern = "abc"; //desired pattern
my $line_no = 1;
my %data;

//Opening the file in read mode
open(INPUT, "<", "file1") or die "Cannot open file :$!\n";

//Parsing the File till the end of file
while(<INPUT>){
   chomp($_);
   my key  = join(":", $line_no, $_); //Use any delimiter to join these. I have used ":" here. You can use " " to add space as delimiter.
   //Check for the pattern and store "something" as the value for the matching hash line
   if($_ =~ /$pattern/){
      $data{$key} = "something";
   } else {
      $data{$key} = "";
   }
   $line_no++;
}
close INPUT;
print Dumper (\%data);
```

Output:

$VAR1 = {

'1: abc line 1a' = "something",

'2: ddf line 2a' = "",

and so on

}